# I have an error when I create a simple TCP client

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, tcp

I have an error when I create a simple TCP client:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in line  client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")

My Python version is 3.8.

```
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80
 
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((target_host, target_port))

client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")

response  = client.recv(4096)
print(response)
```

Comment: You need to encode the message before sending it. Try: `client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n".encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: also an option: `b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n"`